# EmberJS pass variable to default template

Tags: ember.js

So here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div id="top-panel">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="home">
    <ul>
        {{#each}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/router.js"></script>
```

My app.js:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

My router.js:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("home", { path: "/" });
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        $.getJSON("mocks/stub1.json", function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

Now my problem is how can I send a variable to the default template (the one which renders home template inside {{outlet}}).

As you can see I want {{title}} to be a dynamic variable. The problem is, I already have a home route assigned to / path so I am not sure how to make {{title}} dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default template as you call it is named `application` template. So therefore you can define the `title` property on the `ApplicationController` or `ApplicationRoute` as you please. In case you go with the controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  title: 'Foo',
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps.